# Express Static and setHeaders: "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I get the error `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` with the following code.

```
app.use('/assets/u', express.static('./public/img/u', {
  setHeaders: (res, path, stat) => {
    redis.get(`image-mime:1`, (err, reply) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      res.set('Content-Type', reply);
    });
  },
}));
```

I think it has something to do with the callback? Because it I remove the callback in the following way:

```
app.use('/assets/u', express.static('./public/img/u', {
  setHeaders: (res, path, stat) => {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
  },
}));
```

everything works like it should and I get no errors.
Would love some help on this problem.

Edit: When I turn **on** the Chrome devtools' "Disable Cache", the error disappears. And the moment I turn it **off**, the error is back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `setHeaders()` needs to run synchronously. Solution is to reverse the calls:

```js
app.use('/assets/u', (res, res, next) => {
  redis.get(`image-mime:1`, (err, reply) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.set('Content-Type', reply);
    next();
  });
}, express.static('./public/img/u'));
```

The first middleware retrieves the mime-type and calls serve-static only when done, unless an error happens.

Have in mind that it would call redis even when the client already has the latest copy of the object, comparing E-Tags, returning 304 in this case. This should explain why turning on `Disable Cache`, the error doesn't show up. There is a different path when client has got the object already in cache, and when it don't.